# Custom advertising integration with Blogger.com

Tags: advertising, blog, blogger

I want to know if I can use my own advertising solution with my blog hosted at Blogger.com

I am worried that I will not be able to - Google suggests I use its Adsense service and Amazon.

Can I use my own advertising solution?

Does Blogger.com limit the use of alternative advertising solutions compared to paid blog hosting services?

Answer (score 1):

Blogger allows you to add arbitrary HTML content, including Javascript and frames, anywhere in your template.
As long as your advertising system doesn't require server-side code on the blog (or database access), it should work fine.

To do it, go to the `Design` tab, then click `Edit HTML`.
You can then download the full template, add it to source control, edit it as necessary, then upload it to Blogger.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [terms of service](http://www.blogger.com/terms.g) it says

> 1. No Resale of the Service. Unless expressly authorized in writing by Google, you agree not to reproduce, duplicate, copy, sell, trade, resell or exploit for any commercial purposes (a) any portion of the Service, (b) use of the Service, or (c) access to the Service.

That's mainly talking about charging people to use blogger to host their blogs, but selling adverts possibly could be seen as "exploiting for commercial purposes" if they notice what you're doing.